# How to get a nested list of a child by Parent id?

Tags: php, laravel-5, parent-child, categories

I am using [baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) to get nested list of categories. I have a case where I only want to get a child of few parent id. I have used static function `getNestedList("name", null, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")` which gives me all categories nested list separated by space. I want the same response but only for few parent categories.

I tried below code to get my list with where clause but it only works with the first result. I have multiple parent_id and I need the each child listed in an array with space operator.

```
$node = Category::where('name', '=', 'Some category I do not want to see.')->first();

$root = Category::where('name', '=', 'Old boooks')->first();
var_dump($root->descendantsAndSelf()->withoutNode($node)->get());
```

**QUESTION UPDATE**

The issue I was facing to get descendants and self categories list using Baum was just because of wrong entry in my database. I am sorry for that. Now, I am getting my category list using  `descendantsAndSelf()` but the issue is how to created the nested list with `$seperator` ?

I tried to `toHierarchy()` but it only return nested collection. I did not found any function which provides nested list like the function `getNestedList("text", null, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");`. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

As per my updated question, Below is my answer what I actually want to do.

To get list of Descendants with parent I have used below function.

```
public function getSubcategory($id) {
    $node = $this->where('id', $id)->with('children')->first();
    $descendant = $node->getDescendantsAndSelf()->toArray();
    return $this->CreateNestedList("text", $descendant, null, "-");
}
```

> And to create nested loop I have used the same logic of the 
>   function `getNestedList()`. I have created new function inside my model
>   file as below.

```
public function CreateNestedList($column, $data, $key = null, $seperator = ' ') {
        $key = $key ?: $this->getKeyName();
        $depthColumn = $this->getDepthColumnName();

        return array_combine(array_map(function($node) use($key) {
          return $node[$key];
        }, $data), array_map(function($node) use($seperator, $depthColumn, $column) {
          return str_repeat($seperator, $node[$depthColumn]) . $node[$column];
        }, $data));
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong. We must not use RECURSION. This will be result into multiple queries.

Comment: @RonakDattani can you give me same output using [baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum), It can be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
$data=Category::where('id','yourid')->first()->descendants()->get()->pluck('text','id');
```

Comment: I need something like that, but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: then put the detail code I will mark the solution, you can do str_repeat then